# How to get records order by pivot column using laravel elquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to sort records order by `highscore` `desc` that I get top high scored users. I have tried a lot and still trying but could not achieve the task.

Following is working but it does sorting

```
$GameLog = User::with(['games' => function ($q){
    $q->withPivot('highscore','level');
}])->get();
```

I also tried following to achieve it but this is also not working

```
$GameLog = User::with(['games' => function ($q){
    $q->withPivot('highscore','level');
}])->groupBy(DB::raw('highscore DESC'))
->get();
```

I also tried sortBy() function in the loop but still I am facing issue. The first query is returning following result which should be sort by `highscore`

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "fasdfsad",
            "games": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "pivot": {
                        "highscore": 506,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "john",
            "favorite_game_id": null,
            "games": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "pivot": {
                        "highscore": 2340,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "tfyuyu",
            "games": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "pivot": {
                        "highscore": 100,
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone kindly give me any idea how can I fix it I would appreciate. Thank you so much

Edited for Models

In `Game.php`

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_and_game', 'game_id', 'user_id')
        ->withPivot('highscore');
}
```

In `User.php`

```
public function games()
{ 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class, 'user_and_game', 'user_id', 'game_id');
}
```

I would like to appreciate if someone kindly help me about that

Comment: Can someone kindly guide me about this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new model for pivot (`highscore`). For example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Highscore extends Pivot
{
    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    } 

    public function game() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Game::class);
    }
}
```

**Note**: from the example, we are extending from `Pivot` class instead of `Model`.

In the controller you can sort it like this example:

```
$highscores = Highscore::orderByDesc('score')
    ->with('user', 'game')
    ->get();
```

When using a custom pivot table, you need to define it from `User` and `Games` table.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_and_game', 'game_id', 'user_id')
        ->using(Highscore::class)
        ->withPivot('highscore');
}
```